# XSD definition for same elements in an XML

Tags: xml, xsd

I am trying to come up with an XSD complex type for an XML with these contents

```
<SimpleData name="omsId">46</SimpleData>
<SimpleData name="registrationNumber">206-TG-4</SimpleData> 
<SimpleData name="obstacleType">Antenna</SimpleData>  
<SimpleData name="signature">OEI</SimpleData>
<SimpleData name="state">A</SimpleData>
<SimpleData name="maxHeightAGL">75</SimpleData>
<SimpleData name="topElevationAMSL">787</SimpleData>
```

In the example above the elements are the same and each has the same name attribute tag with a different value.

Please suggest.

Thanks

Comment: You haven't explained what you would consider valid and what you would consider invalid. Would it be invalid to have an element with `name="Ghdusn"`? would it be invalid for the element with `name="state"` to have the value `BANANA`?

Comment: yes..the element names are fixed. the values can be anything..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you want a complex type with any name attribute?
If so, how about his:

```
  <element name="SimpleData">
    <complexType>
      <simpleContent>
        <extension base="string">
          <attribute name="name" type="string" use="required"/>
        </extension>
      </simpleContent>
    </complexType>
  </element>
```

Or Do you want the names to be limited to the ones you used above? If that is the case, try this version:

```
  <element name="SimpleData">
    <complexType>
      <simpleContent>
        <extension base="string">
          <attribute name="name" type="MyDatatypes" use="required"/>
        </extension>
      </simpleContent>
    </complexType>
  </element>
  <simpleType name="MyDatatypes">
    <restriction base="string">
      <enumeration value="omsId"/>
      <enumeration value="registrationNumber"/>
      <enumeration value="obstacleType"/>
      <enumeration value="signature"/>
      <enumeration value="state"/>
      <enumeration value="maxHeightAGL"/>
      <enumeration value="topElevationAMSL"/>
    </restriction>
  </simpleType>
```

Also it wasn't clear to me from your question if you wanted any limits on the number of times each element can be used? Should each of them be used exactly ones and in the order you gave or do the above samples help you?

Added a new example based on the feedback, this time restricting the attributes so that each of them is present exactly ones.

You'll need a test on the parent element for SimpleData, I've called it root but you you can use whatever you want.

```
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" elementFormDefault="qualified">
  <xs:element name="root">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" ref="SimpleData"/>
      </xs:sequence>
      <xs:assert test="count(SimpleData) = 7"/>
    </xs:complexType>
    <xs:unique name="UniqueSimpleData">
      <xs:selector xpath="SimpleData" /> 
      <xs:field xpath="@name" /> 
    </xs:unique>
  </xs:element>
  <xs:element name="SimpleData">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:simpleContent>
        <xs:extension base="xs:string">
          <xs:attribute name="name" type="MyDatatypes" use="required"/>
        </xs:extension>
      </xs:simpleContent>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
  <xs:simpleType name="MyDatatypes">
    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
      <xs:enumeration value="omsId"/>
      <xs:enumeration value="registrationNumber"/>
      <xs:enumeration value="obstacleType"/>
      <xs:enumeration value="signature"/>
      <xs:enumeration value="state"/>
      <xs:enumeration value="maxHeightAGL"/>
      <xs:enumeration value="topElevationAMSL"/>
    </xs:restriction>
  </xs:simpleType>
</xs:schema>
```

Two things are new.
First the assert (this works only in XSD 1.1! - please make sure your software supports version 1.1 otherwise you'll get an error message.
The assert checks that you have exactly 7 SimpleData elements present (one for each attribute).
The second new thing is the unique constrain, this ensures that each element attribute combination is used only ones.

With only the unique check you would disallow double entries but it would be possible to omit one from your list and have only 6 of them present, so you really need both of those checks.

Hope this solves your problem.

Comment: The names need to be limited to the ones listed above and each <SimpleData> element needs to have a different name. Each such <SimpleData> element will occur once.The <enumeration> only restricts to one of these but I want all of them in the XML. hope this clarifies..